# Required open port to run hadoop jar from edge node

Tags: hadoop, teradata

I tried to execute a `hadoop jar ...` from an edge node of the cluster (i.e. a node that is  not part of the cluster but is configured to access it) but I get timeout exception, first on a random data node and port, then after a log stating the job is finished in error, I get another timeout connecting to a namenode on port 10020. The edge node being outside of the hadoop cluster, we want to avoid opening ports if possible.

I cannot find documentation on which ports are required to be open from edge node to execute `hadoop jar`, or even better if there is a way to tell hadoop to execute the jar on another node than the edge node I run the command on.

But it works fine if I execute the hadoop jar command on a namenode (didn't try on a data node, but I expect it to work)

Does anyone know:

- what ports are required to execute hadoop jar from an edge node (and related conf)?
- if there is a way to tell hadoop to execute it on a datanode to avoid opening those ports?

Notes:

- the jar I am trying to run is the [teradata-hadoop connector (TDCH) v1.8.4.1](https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/teradata-connector-for-hadoop-tdch-command-line-edition)
- the cluster is a CDP 7.1.7
- `hadoop fs` commands work
- `spark-submit` (in cluster mode) works
- `yarn application` command works

Answer (score 1):

`hadoop jar` first submits code to YARN, so you need ports open for that. Then reads and writes data to datanodes, which finds the addresses from the namenode, so you'll need ports open for both of those (for every datanode).

If you're using Hive queries, then you also need to know ports of the Hiveserver2 instance, the metastore, etc. Similarly, Hbase if using that, and the list goes on... There isn't one port `hadoop jar` uses - it depends on your code

You should reference at least your core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, and yarn-site.xml files to know what ports must be accessed
There isn't a single answer, as it depends what you've set for RPC/HTTP addresses for services.

The edge node should only have open one port for SSH, but maybe also a web server, if you wanted to run some interface like HUE, Spark UI, etc.

The simplest solution is to edit the cluster's / Router firewall to allow TCP traffic from the edge node.

Comment: my understanding is that hadoop would deploy the jar in an application master, and it would be this AM that needs to communicate with all node. I added in my question that yarn command works (at least the application subcommand) so port to yarn are open I think. Why would the edge node where I call `hadoop jar` needs to communicate with anything else than yarn?

Comment: note that the edge node doesn't run anything else than `hadoop fs`, `yarn application` and spark-submit`. Other services such as Hue are running else where.

Comment: Another comment: the first error happens while attempting to communicate with a random data node and port (each call logs different node and port). And those ports number are very large (eg. 38317), so I guess the range is all-ports or the likes

Comment: You can find default ports and addresses at https://apache.github.io/hadoop/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml , but it would be easier to open all TCP ports in the Firewall from the cluster to the edge node.

Comment: `hadoop jar` and `yarn jar` are the same (I prefer the latter)... Neither of these commands should need to contact the namenode unless you are trying to run a JAR file that is stored in HDFS rather than local FS